# Scroll Bar not working in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a program in Java, but for some reason the scroll bar in my bottom most component isn't working. I have no idea why. It should apply a vertical scroll bar to the bottom text area. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;



public class TimerGui extends JFrame
{
private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 300;
private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;

private JPanel topPanel;
private JPanel leftPanel;
private JPanel bottomPanel;

private JLabel topLabel;
private JLabel leftLabel;

private JTextField setTimer;
private JTextArea displayTimer;

private JScrollPane scrollPane;

private JButton startButton;

//no-arg constructor
public TimerGui()
{
    createTopPanel();
    createLeftPanel();
    createBottomPanel();
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
}

//creates the top panel, including the label and text field 
private void createTopPanel()
{
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topLabel = new JLabel("TIMER LAB:");

    final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
    setTimer = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);

    topPanel.add(topLabel);
    topPanel.add(setTimer);

    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

//creates the left panel, which is just a single text label
private void createLeftPanel()
{
    leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftLabel = new JLabel("(1000 milliseconds = 1 second)");

    add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    leftPanel.add(leftLabel);
}


//the listener for the start button
class ClickListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        int speed = Integer.parseInt(setTimer.getText());

        MyListner listener = new MyListner();
        Timer timer = new Timer(speed, listener);
        timer.start(); 
    }
}

class MyListner implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {         
        SimpleDateFormat simpleTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date now = new Date();
        String time = simpleTime.format(now);
        displayTimer.append(time + String.format("%n"));
    }
}

//creates the button, with action listener attached
private void createStartButton()
{
    startButton = new JButton("Start");

    ActionListener listener = new ClickListener();
    startButton.addActionListener(listener);
}

//creates the bottom panel, with the start button and the display text field
private void createBottomPanel()
{
    final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;

    bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    displayTimer = new JTextArea(10, 15);
    displayTimer.setEditable(false);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(displayTimer);
       scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    createStartButton();
    bottomPanel.add(startButton);
    bottomPanel.add(displayTimer);
    bottomPanel.add(scrollPane);
}

}
```

Comment: remove 'bottomPanel.add(displayTimer);'

It is already contained with in the ScrollPane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding both the displayTimer and the JScrollPane that also holds it to the GUI. Don't do this. Just add the JScrollPane since you can add a component only once to a GUI, so you end up adding a JTextArea without a JScrollPane together with an empty JScrollPane (look carefully to the right of the JTextArea). So change this:

```
    createStartButton();
    bottomPanel.add(startButton);
    bottomPanel.add(displayTimer);
    bottomPanel.add(scrollPane);
```

to this:

```
    createStartButton();
    bottomPanel.add(startButton);
    // !! bottomPanel.add(displayTimer);
    bottomPanel.add(scrollPane);
```

Other issues:

- Avoid setting sizes.
- Instead call `pack()` and let the GUI set its own size.

Comment: Thank you! That fixes my problem perfectly!